# Android Room Dao throw checked exception

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a checked exception that I would want my Room DAO method to be able to throw. How can I achieve that?

Here is what I have tried:

```
public class MyCheckedException extends Exception{
}


@Dao
public abstract class FooDao {
    @Transaction
    public void methodThatThrowsCheckedException() throws MyCheckedException  {
        throw new MyCheckedException();
    }
}
```

I am getting build error `error: unreported exception MyCheckedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown FooDao_Impl.super.methodThatThrowsCheckedException();`.

#### Edit:

Some additional info: This is how the generated `methodThatThrowsCheckedException` method looks like

```
@Override
public void methodThatThrowsCheckedException() {
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        FooDao_Impl.super.methodThatThrowsCheckedException();
        __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        __db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway that I can make the generated code have this as the method signature instead? `public void methodThatThrowsCheckedException() throws MyCheckedException`

Comment: I don't think throwing custom Exception could be allowed here . Since the `FooDao_Impl` is auto generated and `Transaction` will return the data or null or empty in case of any error . So you should be handling returned value only .

Comment: @ADM are you saying that currently Room library is not able to generate DAO methods which throws check exception?